# Delphi 10.3 IDE standard toolbar is missing Run with debugging, Run without, and both SAVE buttons

Tags: delphi

I have tried to customize the toolbar, and under Commands, it lists these missing items. It says to drag and drop to any toolbar. I dragged the "run" button, the green triangle and dropped it on the toolbar. Northing happens...no error message. The mouse cursor changes while it is being dragged as expected, but after dropping,
nothing happens except the cursor, which was a square changes back to the normal cursor, an arrow.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you right-click a vacant area on the toolbar, does it come up with a popup menu, which includes "Debug" on it?

Comment: Do you see the corresponding menu items in the main menu, and are they working OK?

Comment: What version of Windows is this installed on? Is Delphi installed in C:\Program Files (x86)? Maybe it's a rights problem.